# R: what is 'adjusted by' in survival analysis?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

male_data:

```
          surgery   age   cancer  survival
a00001        yes  <=50        0        10
a00002        yes   >50        1        15
a00003        no    >50        0         2
.
.
.
.
```

Result:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(survival, cancer) ~ surgery + age, data = male_data)

n= 550517, number of events= 3276

               coef  exp(coef) se(coef)    z  Pr(>|z|)
surgery:yes   -0.03    0.97     0.04   -0.88   0.377
age:>50        3.26   26.09     0.04    78.5  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

             exp(coef)   exp(-coef)   lower .95   upper .95
surgery:yes      0.97         1.03          0.9        1.04      
age:>50         26.09         0.04        24.05       28.3

Concordance= 0.817  (se = 0.005 )
Likelihood ratio test= 7607  on 2 df,   p=<2e-16
Wald test            = 6182  on 2 df,   p=<2e-16
Score (logrank) test = 13993  on 2 df,   p=<2e-16
```

Now I need to fill the result in a new form. But I do not know what "adjusted by" means. Can I find this value in the result? I would appreciate any advice!

[image]

Comment: This is really the wrong place to ask such a question.

Answer (score 0):

In any observational study, you need to define clearly your **exposure** and **outcome** of interest. It seems that your exposure of interest is whether the patient had surgery or not and the outcome either the incidence of cancer or death from cancer. If this is the case, your results are adjusted by age.

You are the only person who can answer this question! It truly depends on the research question and the underlying causal structure you are thinking about.